# SQL: Comparing MAX Dates from Two different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 Tables

### User

[image]

### Attendence

[image]

### Payment

[image]

Now I like to get

GroupID, UserName, MAX(PaymetDate), MAX(AttendenceDate)

Where MAX(PaymetDate) IS LESS THAN MAX(AttendenceDate)

#### This what I have Tried

```
    SELECT  MAX(PaymetDate) AS Paied_Upto
    FROM Payment
    Group by GroupID   

    SELECT  MAX(AttendenceDate) AS Last_ AttendenceDate
    FROM Attendence FULL OUTER JOIN Users ON Attendence.Username = Users.Username
    Group by Users.GroupID
```

But how do get them to work together?

#### Thank

Comment: would you mind explaining how tables are related with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.GroupID, u.UserName, py.LastPaymentDate, at.LastAttendenceDate
FROM User AS u,
(SELECT Username, Max(AttendenceDate) AS LastAttendenceDate FROM Attendence GROUP BY Username) AS at,
(SELECT GroupID, Max(PaymetDate) AS LastPaymentDate FROM Payment GROUP BY GroupID) AS py
WHERE u.UserName=at.Username
AND u.GroupID=py.GroupID
AND py.LastPaymentDate < at.LastAttendenceDate;
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I formatted this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select p.GroupID, u.UserName, MAX(p.PaymetDate), MAX(a.AttendenceDate)
from dbo.Users u
inner join dbo.Attandence a
    ON u.UserName = a.UserName
Inner join dbo.Payment p
    ON u.groupID = p.GroupID
GROUP BY p.GroupID, u.UserName
Having MAX(p.PaymentDate) < MAX(a.attendenceDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you need (**[SqlFiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16752/6)**):

```
select UserName, GroupID, MaxAttendanceDate, MaxPaymentDate
from (
  select 
    u.UserName,
    u.GroupID,
    (select max(AttendanceDate) 
       from Attendance a 
       where a.UserName = u.UserName) as MaxAttendanceDate,
    (select max(PaymentDate) 
       from Payment p
       where p.GroupID = u.GroupId) as MaxPaymentDate
  from [User] u
) x
where MaxAttendanceDate > MaxPaymentDate
```