# MySQL: Select threads and posts, order by latest activity

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

I'd like to get a list of `threads` of a `forum`, ordered by the latest activity:

- created thread
- created post

**Desired output**:

```
Thread name  | Timestamp (Thread) | Timestamp (latest post)
-----------------------------------------------------------
Thread A     | 1                  | 10                 <- old thread, newest post (newer than newest thread)
Thread C     | 3                  | -                  <- newest thread, no post
Thread B     | 2                  | 5
```

**EDIT / possible solution:**

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    IFNULL
    (         
        (
            SELECT p.timestamp 
              FROM posts p 
             WHERE p.thread_id = t.id 
             ORDER BY p.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
        ),
        t.timestamp
    ) AS sorting 
FROM 
    threads t
WHERE t.forum_id = 1
ORDER BY sorting DESC
```

Does anyone have performance advices? Thanks everybody!

Comment: Sample data,desired results.

Comment: A quick google on the subject turned up the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181966/sql-comparing-max-dates-from-two-different-tables There appear to be two options submitted as answers in that post. Im not an expert on SQL so I couldn't say for sure how you would approach this, you may be able to glean some information from they way they have structured their queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*, IFNULL(MAX(p.`timestamp`), t.`timestamp`) AS pts FROM `threads` t, `posts` p WHERE p.`thread_id` = t.`id` AND t.`forum_id`=1 ORDER BY pts DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT threads.name
  , threads.timestamp
  , latest_posts.latest_timestamp
  , GREATEST(threads.timestamp,COALESCE(latest_posts.latest_timestamp,threads.timestamp)) AS sorting
FROM threads
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT thread_id, MAX(timestamp) as latest_timestamp
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY thread_id) as latest_posts
  ON threads.id = latest_posts.thread_id
ORDER BY sorting
```